# legend not centering correctly with margins in firefox

Tags: html, css, jeet-grid

I'm hoping someone can spot the issue here, as unfortunately I can't easily reproduce it in a jsfiddle (**Edit:** turns out I can, see the jsfiddle linked below), so something else must be at play.

See the attached screenshots, the unexpected result in Firefox, and the expected result in Chrome respectively:

[image]

[image]

The relevant CSS (well, Stylus):

```
legend
      center()
      width 750px
      font-size 28px
      margin-top 80px
      margin-bottom 20px
      color color-text
```

All containers (`fieldset`, `form`) have a width of 100%.

(The `center()` is from [jeet.gs](http://jeet.gs) - seems to just add a `float: none`, `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto` - but you can see the outcome in the screenshots.)

Here's a jsfiddle that seems to work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/nfLudt59/1/ - which tells me that it's not an issue inherent in the legend element. **EDIT:** I hadn't wrapped the legend in a `fieldset`, when this is done, the problem **IS** reproduced.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a legend in a fieldset behaves different from one outside it, so is the problem reproducible a fiddle when you put the fieldset in?

Comment: Ah - good point - and yes! Jsfiddle updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is clearly a discrepency between Chrome and Firefox, combining an answer found elsewhere with some MAcGyver'ing the solution seems to be:

1. Use `align="center"` on the legend (inline)
2. Apply `text-align: left` to the legend via CSS

Updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfLudt59/3/

HTML

```
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">
    Hello
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
fieldset{
  width: 100%;
}
legend{
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```